# react router not rendering child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, children

I'm learning react router and just cut off part of the Github's [page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) and I'm using webpack and http-server to host my dev environement at http://localhost:8080. When I go to to the routh path, I see my App component, but I don't see the Users component when I go to http://localhost:8080/users.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div>app</div>
  }
});
// etc.

var Users = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>users</div>
    )
  }
})



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. So the thing is, `users` is a child of `app`. So whenever you render `/users`, first it renders `app`. But inside the app definition, you have to specify where you want to render its children with: `{this.props.children}`. So either add it to the definition:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
});
// etc.
```

Or bring users to the same level as app (I guess you don't want to do this):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users" component={Users}>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

For reference: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router#whats-it-look-like

Comment: hi @fodma1 I did what you mentioned in the first suggestion and it didn't work. did you have to change anything else?

Comment: @jlei Well, I have another idea: How does your HTML look like? Your target is `document.getElementById('main')`, I used `document.body`

Comment: I changed it to document.body and it still doesn't work - do you mind. the app component still works though, so it's weird that the users component doesn't show up. i've edited it to include my HTML, it's pretty basic

Comment: i tried bringing users up to the same line too, but it didn't work either. what is the URL you're using to see the users component? is it http://localhost:8080/users?

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
             <ul>
               <li><Link to="/users">/users</Link></li>
             </ul>
             <div>app</div>
             <div>{this.props.children}</div>
           </div>
  }
})

var Users = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>users</div>
    )
  }
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

What changed:

- I added `<div>{this.props.children}</div>` where the child (in this case the Users) components get rendered
- I added `<Link to="/users">/users</Link>`.

Now if you click the link, it works like a charm!

Please note, that if you are using the webpack dev server, the browser URL is not gonna be the same as the URL that you are actually on. ) I had this issue, though you might have the same struggle). So instead of `http://localhost:8000/webpack-dev-server/` open up `http://localhost:8000/` (which redirects to `http://localhost:8000/#/?_k=some_weird_hash`) and `http://localhost:8000/#/users` gonna work.